# How do you solve this puzzle?

Tags: number-sequence

[image]

I don't know how to solve it. Please help me.

Comment: Hi Daniel, and welcome to Puzzling :) Where is this puzzle from, please? All puzzles from elsewhere need to have their source accredited or they may end up being closed. Also, do you have any ideas about this puzzle yourself? What have you tried so far? This would be useful for us to know... Thanks!

Comment: I don't speak any east Asian languages but it looks like this could be Japanese. Could you translate the two different phrases? The 79 and 6 look like they could be the key but without knowing we could go through a lot of guess work.

Comment: I think it's Korean

Comment: I've put this on hold pending clarification of where it comes from. Daniel, we do require that if you post a puzzle someone else made then you give full credit to the creator, explicitly enough that others can find the original source. (I'm sorry that the on-hold notice says "off-topic", which of course isn't quite right. There are stupid technical reasons why it has to be that way.)